# Add individual user accounts

Tags: asp.net-core

I am developing a project in ASP.NET CORE, it is already in progress, and there arose the need to create the login, however how to do this with the project already in progress? How to enter as Indivual User Accounts? I've seen several tutorials, but always starting from scratch, a new project, and the project is already started. What's the best way out?

Comment: Your best bet is to start a new project with individual auth as a reference and then migrate over relevant stuff into your existing project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a general note, with modern frameworks that provide generators/scaffolding I sometimes end up just running the examples and then do a recursive compare between the existing project and the new project.

I can then carefully apply the necessary patches to bring the changes into the existing project

(This is useful for a number of things, - something I use it for more frequently is to bring a forgotten project up to date and streamline it.)

Comment: It was the only solution I found, I created a project from scratch, and I threw his data into my current project, and that's how it worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core 2.1 you can scaffold out identity into existing projects. See [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on how to do this.